# Implementing Feed Comments with Get Stream in PHP

Tags: php, yii, getstream-io

We are looking to integrate [GetStream](https://getstream.io/) with our existing PHP Yii framework based site. Before we jump into integration, would like to know how we can implement features like Comments and Likes?

I'm using the [GetStream/stream-php](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-php) library. We are able to send and retrieve the activity feed info. but i just couldn't wrap my head around on how to do **Likes** and **Comments** features on the activities.